# How to get key value pair data from nested objects in reactjs? Here is the example that i want to achieve

Tags: reactjs, json, object, react-hooks, react-forms

help me out with the API response I have to work with

```
[
 {
        "attributes": {
            "vehColour": "Value",
            "vehMake": "Value",
            "vehModel": "Value",
            "vehVin": "Value",
            "vehVariant": "Value",
            "vehImage": "Link"
        },
        "dataId": "test23",
        "features": {
            "HPC": {
                "CP": {
                    "Apps": {
                        "App3": {
                            "PreviousVersion": "2.2.0",
                            "DateOfUpdate": "string",
                            "CompatibilityDetails": "C",
                            "CurrentVersion": "0.0.1"
                        },
                        "App2": {
                            "PreviousVersion": "3.3.0",
                            "DateOfUpdate": "string",
                            "CompatibilityDetails": "C",
                            "CurrentVersion": "0.0.1"
                        }
                    },
                    "Hardware": {
                        "PartNo": "CP-P",
                        "AssemblyNo": "CP-P"
                    }
                },
                "ADAS": {
                    "Apps": {
                        "App4": {
                            "PreviousVersion": "0.0.0",
                            "DateOfUpdate": "string",
                            "CompatibilityDetails": "C",
                            "CurrentVersion": "0.0.1"
                        },
                        "App3": {
                            "PreviousVersion": "0.0.3",
                            "DateOfUpdate": "string",
                            "CompatibilityDetails": "C",
                            "CurrentVersion": "0.0.1"
                        }
                    },
                    "Hardware": {
                        "PartNo": "ADAS-P",
                        "AssemblyNo": "ADAS-A"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
       so on....
    }
]
```

From this response I want to get output in the form of table in reactjs, the table needs to be updated as per the path example: if user clicks on HPC button he will get 2 objects ADAS button and CP button like a tree, if user clicks on ADAS button then he will be shown ADAS children i.e., Apps button and Hardware button, further if user clicks on Apps button a table should be displayed with table headers as "PreviousVersion","DateOfUpdate","CompatibilityDetails","CurrentVersion" for App4 and for App3 similarly the data for table body should be their values i.e., "0.0.0", "string", "C", "0.0.1" as per the values getting from object, if user clicks on Hardware button header of table should be updated with "PartNo" and "AssemblyNo" as per the key and values displayed from object ,

Similar way to the HPC --> CP --> Apps or Hardware --> App3 or App2

I have tried to execute code multiple times as,

```
<table className="transparent-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {keys.map(key => (
              <th style={{ color: "white" }} key={key}>
                {JSON.stringify(key)}
              </th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            {keys.map(key => (
              <td style={{ color: "white" }} key={key}>
                {JSON.stringify(data[key])}
              </td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

getting output in the form of strings but that is not expected , I want clean output in the form of table